# Calculate hours of the day stores are open

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have three columns in a spreadsheet.

[image]

These three columns represent a stores' hours for a given day (each store has a set of columns for each day).

I would like to populate each cell in this table

[image]

with the number of stores open at that particular time of that particular day.

What kind of formula can I use to calculate this? What is my best approach to solving this problem?

*Example:*
Using the given information would be that for Monday, there are 3 stores open at 1:00 PM. The cell corresponding to Monday 1:00 PM would be populated with a 3. At 4:00 PM, there are 2 stores open. The cell for 2:00 PM would be populated with a 2. This would occur for each hour of each day.

Comment: Are all time entries stored as times, so you can do time math, or are they stored as text?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have edited the image and given an example. The time entries are currently stored as a time and are rounded up to the next highest hour.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution based on simple IF & AND function combination. There might be a leaner way to do the same. Formula needs to be mapped for each master table representing Store Open & Close timings for each weekday.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This requires 2 operations
 a. To determine if a store is open at a particular time
 b. To add stores if they are open

this will require [nested formulas](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Nest-a-function-within-a-function-9b98d544-85f4-4af9-a134-ccbb6164c336) & [mixed references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21)
(follow the links to learn more, & try them on your own, the below answer will not make sense otherwise)

if store is open then 1, if closed then 0, & add 0s & 1s to get sum of all open stores

add more if functions for more stores & adjust references for weekdays as shown in screenshot below

once the references are determined for the 1st row, use autofill for the rest of the cells in subsequent rows

I have used 3 stores as an example here, add more stores with `+` in the formula bar

For Monday,

[image: Formula for Monday]

For Tuesday,

[image: Formula for Tuesday]

& so on

**Note**: This will work only if the time is stored as number, not text. If it is text, please format it as number before trying this solution

Comment: There are roughly 500 stores for me to process. Would this method require me to manually add the if statements with nested functions to the formula?

Comment: yes, that's the only why I can think of doing something like this in excel.